# Madred's Bloodrazor on Riven

Tags: league-of-legends

Normally you should play Riven totally on AD ( since all her Spells stack with AD ). But I was just wondering - when I play vs a tanky team with many HP ( Warmogs and stuff ) I usually go for Madred's Bloodrazor when I play AD Carry ( e.g. Ashe ), because of the 4% Dmg from the max. health.

Now my question is - would it be reasonable to go for Madred's Bloodrazor with Riven too? Because normally you wouldn't try to get Rivens Attack Speed up... If no Bloodrazor, what would be another option for her against targets with much HP ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you shouldn't use Madred's Bloodrazor on Riven:

- Riven scales badly with bonus attack speed, because she should aim to attack only after every ability use. This means not only bonus attack speed from Razor is wasted, but also you won't be using Razor efficiently, since the item procs *do* scale with attackspeed.
- Riven has no magical attacks, and thus has no need to use Magic Penetration/Reduction. Which means Razor procs will hit enemies full Magic Resistance, making the item even worse.

What to do instead:

- Stack AD. Riven has great AD scaling, and you can always use more of it. Remember that it also makes your shield stronger!
- Stack Lifesteal. Since Riven's passive-boost on autoattacks counts for lifesteal, this can make enormous difference, especially in 1v1. Also, lifesteal scales with the AD you're already stacking. Stacking Bloodthirsters can be legitimate tactic on Riven. If you want advantage earlier in the game, stacking Doran's Blades is also very good.
- Don't forget some Armor Penetration/Reduction. Brutalizer gives good flat bonus for early game, plus some AD and some CDR. For late game, Last Whisper gives percentage-based bonus, and yes - more AD!
- If you are in a teamfight: don't focus the HP stacking opponents - go for the squishies instead. Other people in your team should be better prepared for clearing out the tough guys later (maybe even by having the Bloodrazor, if they can use it better and if the situation warrants it).

Comment: Great, detailled answer! That cleared things up for me pretty much!! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Bloodrazor doesn't make too much sense on Riven. Most of her damage comes from abilities, *not* from autoattacks. That means the bonus effect damage and the attack speed you get from the Bloodrazor aren't going to be in effect as Riven's executing her bread and butter.

Comment: Thats actually not true. Rivens passive ( gaining more AD after using a spell ) and also her Ulti ( gaining +20% AD ) just "buff" her Auto Attack. Her Shield doesn't do any damage at all. So in fact her main damage comes from the Auto Attacks and NOT from Q and W

Comment: @Toby The AD she gets only applies to the next *one* autoattack. All this means is she should mix up abilites and autoattacks as much as possible. Which means she should generally not be performing sustained autoattacks. Which means that everything I said is true.

Comment: Okay I see where youre going with the mix between ability and Auto Attack - But saying that most of her damage comes from abilites is just wrong, since its still the Auto Attacks which do the actualy damage. Saying something like that would rather fit on Lux. Don't get me wrong, I think I get what you want to say, just pointing out it was a bit vague

Comment: All of Riven's burst and power comes from her abilities, the autoattacks you lay down in the middle are not as frequent as say Ashe, or Tryndamere whose damage relys solely on auto. So what @StrixVaria is saying (I think) is you would probably be able to deal out more damage and be more effective with other items.

Comment: Is bloodrazor bad on riven - yes. Are riven's auto attacks weak? Absolutely not. Auto attacks are rivens bread and butter and are what seperates a good riven from a bad one.